# Strange SQL statement error in SQLAlchemy-Flask

Tags: python, sql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy in Flask to connect to my Postgres server, and now I want to execute some raw SQL to insert a column into a table. I am getting this error, however:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE user ADD COLUMN permissions INTEGER
                    ^
 'ALTER TABLE user ADD COLUMN permissions INTEGER' {}
```

As you can see, it says there is an SQL error, although I have no idea what I could be doing wrong.

This is the very simple function that executes the command:

```
@staticmethod
def addColumn():
    db.engine.execute('ALTER TABLE user ADD COLUMN permissions INTEGER')
```

The `db` object otherwise works perfectly, and there is nothing wrong with the connection or anything of the sort.

I feel like I'm overlooking something very simple, but I just can't figure out what it is. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Does it work when you put your table name between double quotes? Also bear in mind that postgres names are case-sensitive.

Comment: That was it, Hyperboreus! I never knew double quotes were needed there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) say that `USER` is a reserved keyword, and needs to be quoted to be used as an identifier.

```
Key Word      PostgreSQL      SQL 99      SQL 92
USER          reserved        reserved    reserved
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `user` a reserved word and thus needing to be referenced specially in SQL statement?